# Square reader: Control the card type accepted: Credit or Debit

Tags: square

My Android kiosk app needs to take Debit card payments only using the Square payment reader API

Is there a way using square API to reject all other types of card apart from Debit?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on why you are looking to only accept debit cards?

Comment: This is a limitation of the app specification - no credit cards, only debit.